# Where can I find some of the best practices and ux guides for webapp?

Tags: usability, user-centered-design

I am working on improving a web app UX. Please provide sources for getting the best design practices and research on user-centered design?

Comment: Consider *doing* research rather than *getting* research. Get to know who your users are and what they need to accomplish when using your app, and support those tasks. It's unlikely that anyone has already done that research on your particular users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use many methods but I would recommend you some points that can improve the whole experience.

1. Use [bootstrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/css/)  first(for the UI and frontend) and align everything in columns. Be it 1-2-3-4-6-12 column.
2. provide the breathing space to text. Letter spacing should be at least 1.15 and can vary up to 1.5.
3. You can follow the google's design library and instead of using the gray fonts, use black or any dark color fonts with the opacity.
4. if you want to make the navigation healthy, try reverse card sorting and card sorting to have a compact header and nested header
5. Use breadcrumbs.
6. After making the whole platform and also while making the platform, follow [UX Checklist](https://uxchecklist.github.io/) so that you will not break the experience
7. And last but not the least, Do a [heuristics](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/) check of the web app.